# How to expand the collapse when open the page using angular ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

**Scenario**

I am trying to make the collapse expand open when page started.

I have 2 part of HTML code, one is icons and related click function in the angular code. the second part of HTML is the data part showing the data after the click.

and the expand function allows an opening switch between more or less.

question is how do make it stay open when the page is loaded it. ? 
I tried the number of ways to do it, but it stays collapse. \

please make some suggestion , what is wrong is with the method.

**Code**

HTML

```
<td uib-tooltip="{{a.s.length}} s" tooltip-enable="a.s.length > 1" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="left">
            <span class="auc-table__s-moreless-place">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pointer" aria-hidden="true"  ng-if="a._sExpanded + 1 < a.s.length" ng-click="expandCollapses(a, true)" uib-tooltip="Show more" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="auc-table__s-moreless-place">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pointer" aria-hidden="true" ng-if="a._sExpanded" ng-click="expandCollapses(a, false)" uib-tooltip="Show less" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></span>
            </span>
        </td>
```

HTML data

```
 <tr ng-if="a._sExpanded" ng-repeat="b in a.s.slice(1, a._sExpanded + 1)">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ bcv('Firm', a, b) }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="auc-table__col--auc-table__col--numbers">{{ b.volume }}</td>
        <td class="auc-table__col--auc-table__col--numbers">{{ bcv('Price', a, b) }}</td>
        <td>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pointer modify margin" uib-tooltip="Modify Order" aria-hidden="true" ng-if="::bcv('canModify', a, b)" ng-click="openDialog(a, b)"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pointer cancel margin" uib-tooltip="Cancel Order" aria-hidden="true" ng-if="::bcv('canCancel', a, b)" ng-click="cancel(a, b)"></span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
   </tr>
```

Angular

```
    $scope.expandCollapses = function (auc, expand) {
        var pageSize = $scope.sScroll.pageSize;
        var expanded = auc._sExpanded || 0;
        var ls = auc.s && auc.s.length || 0;


        // expanded += pageSize - (expanded ? 0 : 1);


        if (expand) {
            if (expanded + 1 < ls) {
                expanded += pageSize - (expanded ? 0 : 1);

                console.log("open");

            }
        }
        else {
            if (expanded) {
                if (expanded - ls >= pageSize) {
                    expanded = Math.ceil(ls / pageSize) * pageSize;
                }

                expanded = (expanded >= pageSize) ? expanded - pageSize : 0;
                console.log("close " + expanded);

            }
        }

        auc._sExpanded = expanded;
    };
```

Comment: You might need to show a [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. It is also not clear what variable "a" is. Otherwise, you just need `a._sExpanded` to set to be **true** on page reload.

Comment: I will update this into plunker later today .. thanks for reply !

Comment: and btw  auc._sExpanded =   a._sExpanded I have to change that

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You just want to open and close some text when clicking on some icons, right ?

Eg:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  <td ng-click="item.moreIsShown = !item.moreIsShown">Show more</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="item.moreIsShown">
 <td>Some extra data</td>
</tr>
```

To toggle visibility You do not need a special function, just play it in inline.

To make it work, I think you need to set the attribute You wish to toggle in your repeated collection.

Eg:

```
angular.forEach($scope.yourCollection, function(item) {
 item.moreIsShown = false;
});
```

I hope that I understood your question correctly and I hope this helps.

Comment: its an individual object property in my case, not the controller instance property. will not be this easy lol